# Distance in seconds between moving vehicles

Tags: speed, distance

If two cars are moving in the same direction. 
let’s say ego car is in the front and another follower car. the speed, location in x, y coordinates of both cars are given.

How to calculates the distance between the cars in seconds? 
I have tried the following formula:

time = euclidean distance / (ego speed – follower speed), but something seems not correct.

Can anyone please answer?

Comment: So what is it that seems incorrect?

Comment: I am getting really small values which kept me wondering since my simulation is showing huge distances.

Comment: You need to include a time variable in your formula .... the longer the cars have been travelling the greater the distance (and time) between the cars.

Comment: Which time are you talking about? A time difference indicates a time period between two events - which two events? When the cars pass each other might be one event (they are at the same location), but what is the second event? Perhaps when they are a set distance apart?

Comment: @levitopher  so basically I want to calculate the gap/distance between the cars in seconds. From the gap in time,
 I want to make a safety decision.

Comment: @Sarah: You see why what you ask troubles me right? Literally, both the words "gap" and "distance" *cannot* be measured by time - they are measured in length. However, the answer might be simple - if the *relative* speed between the front car and the back car is $v$, separated by a distance $d$, you will hit the front car in a time period $d/v$. (assuming the back car is traveling faster then the front, and no one changes their speed).

Comment: @levitopher thank you very much for replying back. You are totally correct. The word (gap) is very misleading. I am working with another two partners and they are using gap all the time. therefore, I picked it from them. However, I calculated the time using the formula mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ be the first car and $B$ the second (follower). The relative speed between them is $v=v_A-v_B$. If the mean speed is constant, you can use the formula you described
$$t=\frac{d}{v}$$
where d is the known distance at a time $t_0$. However, what does this equation tell you? If the cars have the same speed, time will be infinity, that is, $v=0$ and they will never meet. In cases $v_B<v_A$ or $v_B>v_A$ we are calculating the time $B$ will take to reach $A$ by assuming the latter stopped. It does not mean much more than this if you think about it.

Be sure you converted your units (km, seconds, etc...) to the correct ones.

Comment: Thank you very much. you made the idea clear enough.